# system preferences/ typescript installation

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble downloading typescript.
 Error Message" The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user." 
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly did you do? Also explain in details what you run it on: OS, versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or macOS, run

```
sudo npm i -g typescript
```

And if you're using Windows, first run as administrator and then

```
npm i -g typescript
```

Comment: Why not install it into the project? That way you avoid potential problems with running multiple versions of `tsc`

Comment: I agree with local installation of almost all packages, but in case of TS, to make using `tsc` cli easier, I recommend going with global installation. Also, IDEs like VS Code allow you to pick between local and global versions of TS in case there is a difference. Just my personal opinion.